# Can i define a function to be used in a function pointer, in a constructor argument

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I am trying to create a button type system which has four funtcions (activate, deactivate, select, deselect), and i have these four functions as function pointers.

I was wondering if it was at all possible to have these be arguments in the constructor, and then be able to define the functions on the fly in the constructor.

something like:

```
Button({(if a == 1) a++},{(if a == 2) a--})
```

etc.

I dont really know what this would be called if it is possible so its really hard to accurately search for what im looking for.

Thanks

Comment: Like Signal slots in Qt?

Comment: You can use a lambda. You might also find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042407/defining-function-inside-function-call) helpful.

Answer (score 3):

It's called lambda expressions. In C++11 you can use this:

```
Button([](int&a){if (a == 1) a++;},[](int&a){if (a == 2) a--;})
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++ 11 you can use lambda expressions.

You can even take them as [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) arguments if you want to store them for later calls in other member functions for example.

Declare your constructor this way:

```
Button(std::function<void(int&)> func1, std::function<void(int&)> func2);
```

and use lambdas when creating an instance:

```
Button myButton([](int &a){a++;}, [](int &a){a--;});
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f041983695166e5c)